# Ubuntu Mobile OS for my Nokia C7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nokia

I Have a Nokia C7 and would love to use ubuntu mobile OS. Is there any plans of releasing for Nokia C7 phones as well? I guess the hardware is same as any standard touch phone...

Comment: See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices for a list of devices that are in the progress of having touch ported to them and their operational status.

Comment: First you need to unlock bootloader, so no one is working on it. 2nd thing, you need hardware drivers that is compatible with android, that is also not available. 3rd is does your phone has 4Gb internal memory (not external sd card), so it doesn't meet min. requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I'd say no. Porting an OS to a device is far more complicated than you think. It usually requires intimate knowledge of a devices hardware and many manufacturers do not provide this information, requiring porters to literally dissect the workings of a device in order to compile the needed drivers and software. Doing so is a very long and drawn out process and even then the task may not succeed. Even devices as popular as the Samsung Galaxy S2 and S3 (international versions) aren't getting popular Custom Android ROMs like Cyanogenmod because the Devs can no longer spare the immense effort that would be required to build the necessary software to run the OS properly and Samsung isn't being forthcoming about the inner workings of their Hardware.

In the end a phone like your Nokia probably won't be seeing Ubuntu any time soon.